# Workflow instances page, cannot find?

Tags: 2010, workflow, sharepoint-foundation

I cannot find, for the life of me, the page that displays the instances of a workflow and the ability to delete past instances.  I've made a ton of changes and done a ton of testing which I'm assuming probably created a ton of instances of the workflow.  I just can't seem to locate this page to delete the instances, did the link go missing for some reason?

Version: SPF 2010 SP1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went to SPD and then to the list.  At the top is a button called Workflow Associations, when you click on that it takes you to the link.

Still a mystery as to why the link disappeared on the actual list properties area.  I'll sum it up to a nuance with Foundation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to remove the previous versions/instances of a workflow you can go into the library settings/workflow settings/remove workflow and there will be a list of the workflows that are currently on the list.

Once in here you will notice a listing for how many instances are running, and options to allow, no new instances and remove.  The previously worflows should be set to "No New Instances"  Change this to "Remove" and click on ok.  This will remove all running instances of previous versions.

Comment: Where you say - library settings/workflow settings/remove workflow - it is actually not there anymore, disappeared. Yet, I know a workflow is attached to that library (or in my case, a list).